# Kubernetes installation on fedora meets a package conflict

Tags: docker, kubernetes, fedora, fedora-27

When I follow the kubernetes guide to install kubernetes on my local machine which runs fedora 27. I have already installed docker-ce 17.12(followed the Docker CE documentation).

bellow is the install output. is there any body can figure out what should I do to make kubernetes installed but also keep my docker-ce?

```
[ian@thinkpad ~]$ sudo LANG=en_US.UTF-8 dnf install kubernetes
Last metadata expiration check: 7:31:34 ago on Sat 13 Jan 2018 12:51:44 PM CST.
Error: 
 Problem: package kubernetes-node-1.7.3-1.fc27.x86_64 requires docker, but none of the providers can be installed
  - package docker-ce-17.12.0.ce-1.fc27.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by docker-2:1.13.1-42.git4402c09.fc27.x86_64
  - package docker-ce-17.12.0.ce-1.fc27.x86_64 conflicts with docker provided by docker-2:1.13.1-26.gitb5e3294.fc27.x86_64
  - problem with installed package docker-ce-17.12.0.ce-1.fc27.x86_64
  - package kubernetes-1.7.3-1.fc27.x86_64 requires kubernetes-node = 1.7.3-1.fc27, but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
(try to add '--allowerasing' to command line to replace conflicting packages or '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
[ian@thinkpad ~]$ docker version
Client:
 Version:       17.12.0-ce
 API version:   1.35
 Go version:    go1.9.2
 Git commit:    c97c6d6
 Built: Wed Dec 27 20:12:17 2017
 OS/Arch:       linux/amd64

Server:
 Engine:
  Version:      17.12.0-ce
  API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:   go1.9.2
  Git commit:   c97c6d6
  Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:14:50 2017
  OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
  Experimental: false
[ian@thinkpad ~]$
```

Comment: Looks like the `kubernetes` package has a dependency over the `docker` package provided by fedora default repositories, while you installed docker-ce from an external repository. Try removing docker-ce and installing `docker`

Comment: but I want to keep my docker-ce and use it with kubernetes, that is why I add this question?

Answer (score 3):

Just requested for push of f27 update of kubernetes-1.9.1 [1] to the stable repository that allows to install either docker or docker-ce. It should take day or 2 to transit. Meantime you can install the kubernetes-node rpm from the update [1]. Tested that locally. Let me know if it does not work for you.

[1] https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2018-d0a64cb26c

Regards
Jan

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1534508) and an [update is pending](https://bodhi.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-2018-d0a64cb26c). Eventually, that will be in the updates set for F27 proper. In the meantime, you can get it from updates-testing, by doing:

```
sudo dnf --enablerepo=updates-testing install kubernetes
```

... and if that works for you, please add feedback on the pending update.